# Laravel sqlite DB connection error

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, laravel

In Laravel 5.3 I am using `SQLite` as my default `DB` connection and, my .env file I removed all `MySQL` connection details. when I use `artisan` command and `tinker` command to create a new entry and fetch entries are **working fine**. but from the `controller` or `eloquent` I cannot fetch or add a record, it throws strange MySQL **connection fail error**.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused 

in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead',
 'homestead', 'secret', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 55
```

Comment: is your mysql up and running?

Comment: no, but I'm using sqlite

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the DB_CONNECTION element in the .env, Laravel will try to use de default configuration, defined in the file config/database.php

The default config is

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

so you probably are trying to use MySQL

If you want to use SQLite, you should add the next line in the .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

and adjust the

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

in the config/database.php or put your SQLite path in the DB_DATABASE variable, in the .env file.

```
DB_DATABASE='your SQLite file path'
```